# How to display errors from JSON response in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an AJAX form to change password, I want to display all the validation errors in a HTML DIV.

Below is my code, it's working fine to submit the form, but I can't pass the errors to the DIV, I keep getting:  `[object Object]` .

```
var url = "/posts/editProfile"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#profileForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {

           alert(data); // show response from the php script.

       },

       error: function(data)
       {

        console.log(data);

        $("#response").text(data);

       }

     });

e.preventDefault(); 

});
```

`<div id="response">
   <!-- output here -->
</div>`

Here's a screenshot of the response I got in the Console.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, there's your answer. The data is a javascript object. I mean, you can do JSON.stringify(data) if you want to dump all that stuff.

Comment: Which of the messages in responseJSON do you want to show?

Comment: All of them, just  what's between ```[" ... "]```

Comment: You can achieve this by either calling each property explicitly as i mentioned bellow data.responseJSON.responseText, or itterate through the properties of the data.responseJSON object, get the values and display them

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to set the inner text of a div element by simply passing the error object that's why you are getting [object Object] I'd suggest you examine your error object in debug mode, or by simply printing it as you did actually, and instead of doing

```
$("#response").text(data);
```

do something like

```
$("#response").text(data.responseJSON.responseText);
```

But that will simply dump some error text within the DIV, i guess you want to show some meaningful validation to your users, to achieve this simply use your error object to display proper data whichever way it suits you best.

Comment: There is no `errorMessage` property in the returned object.

Comment: Well, that's why I said that it will be a good idea to examine the error object that is returned from the API that you are using. Check the edit I did, I missed the responseJSON property...

Comment: ```data.responseJSON.responseText``` didn't worked. ```data.responseText``` returned the result to the div, but it's not showing right, it's like this : ```{"email":["O campo email \u00e9 obrigat\u00f3rio."]```, how can I display just the message between double quotes?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't [feed the vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)...

Comment: Try var err = JSON.parse(data.responseJSON.responseText);
then err.whatEverProperyYouWannaCall ....

Answer (score 1):

this question is about more than three years, and until now no answer, I find it, but I'm sure you have found a solution to this problem.
this easy way,  my solution is:

```
error: function(error)
{
    // this Error is an Object
    var errors = error.responseJSON.errors;
    // Loop this object and pring Key or value or both
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
         console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
 }
```